# Using Python & NLP, how can I extract certain text strings & corresponding numbers preceding the strings from Excel column having a lot of free text?

Tags: python, excel, nlp

I am relatively new to Python and very new to NLP (and nltk) and I have searched the net for guidance but not finding a complete solution. Unfortunately the sparse code I have been playing with is on another network, but I am including an example spreadsheet. I would like to get suggested steps in plain English (more detailed than I have below) so I could first try to script it myself in Python 3. Unless it would simply be easier for you to just help with the scripting... in which case, thank you.

Problem: A few columns of an otherwise robust spreadsheet are very unstructured with anywhere from 500-5000 English characters that tell a story. I need to essentially make it a bit more structured by pulling out the quantifiable data. I need to:

1) Search for a string in the user supplied unstructured free text column (The user inputs the column header) (I think I am doing this right)

2) Make that string a NEW column header in Excel (I think I am doing this right)

3) Grab the number before the string (This is where I am getting stuck. And as you will see in the sheet, sometimes there is no space between the number and text and of course, sometimes there are misspellings)

4) Put that number in the NEW column on the same row (Have not gotten to this step yet)

I will have to do this repeatedly for multiple keywords but I can figure that part out, I believe, with a loop or something. Thank you very much for your time and expertise...

[image: Example of spreadsheet with unstructured free text]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, first we need to obtain the numbers from the string of text.

```
cell_val = sheet1wb1.cell(row=rowNum,column=4).value
```

This will create a list containing every number in the string

`new_ = [int(s) for s in cell_val.split() if s.isdigit()]`

`print(new_)`

You can use the list to assign the values to the column.
Then define the value of the 1st number in the list to the 5th column

```
sheet1wb1.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value = str(new_[1])
```

Comment: Ideally, I want user to input 'pieces of bread' and script will add a new column called 'pieces of bread' and then in each row of 'pieces of bread' would be numbers corresponding to the number of 'pieces of bread' (even if 'pieces' or 'bread' is spelled wrong). So that is why I was thinking natural language processing - using tokenization maybe to split up the cell into all the words and create a list from that, and then somehow find the number before 'pieces of bread' by going back some number of elements of the list to find it. I just don't know the best way to go about finding that number.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't get that from what you wrote above. Then to do that I guess the best way would be to get the index of the numbers in the string, use those to slice the string into the "pieces of bread" etc... I've made something similar before, will try find it later today when I get the time

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found what I am looking for. https://community.esri.com/thread/86096 has 3 or 4 scripts that seem to do the trick. Thank you..!